# Wordpress page edit, Cannot change page view

Tags: wordpress

I'm hoping someone can help me.
I went onto edit a page on Wordpress and changed the page view to 'Fullscreen mode' and now I cannot change it back as the bar is cut off my page.

Please see original [This is how it should be / normally displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMYjN.png)

[This is how it currently is, Also doesn't show me the page title and the top bar is cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xS0y.png)

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. try login using a different browser, also make sure it's not zoomed in (CMD+0)
2. copy this code in themes function.php to permanently disable fullscreen mode

   ```
     if (is_admin()) { 
    function pt_disable_editor_fullscreen_by_default() {
    $script = "jQuery( window ).load(function() { const isFullscreenMode = wp.data.select( 'core/edit-post' ).isFeatureActive( 'fullscreenMode' ); if ( isFullscreenMode ) { wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).toggleFeature( 'fullscreenMode' ); } });";
    wp_add_inline_script( 'wp-blocks', $script );
   ```

   }
   add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets','pt_disable_editor_fullscreen_by_default' );}

Comment: remember to add the absolute last line as well, i don't know why it wasn't included in the code

Comment: Thank you, I have managed the change the page view by changing the position of it in css and editing that way, However My 'Document|Block' widget on the right isn't there, I click on 'settings' and nothing happens... any ideas?

Comment: Try login using a different browser.

Comment: Does the same thing

Comment: Try to disable all plugins, then reload the page, you can then reactivate each plugin one by one.